# Big O notation where the "squeeze" starts at $0$?

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

There is the standard notation : $$f = O(g) \iff \exists M > 0, \,\exists n_0 > 0, \,\forall n > n_0, \quad \left|f(n)\right| \leq M\cdot g(n)
$$
But this is not adequate for a paper I'm writing because I need to force $n_0$ to be $0$, i.e. : $$
\exists M > 0, \,\forall n > 0, \quad \left|f(n)\right| \leq M\cdot g(n)
$$

I'll be using this a lot, so a synthetic notation like $f = O(g)$ is required.

Is there a standard notation for this? Or a not so standard one?

Comment: Can you define $\hat{g}(n)=g(n-1)$?

Comment: @NicNic8, sure yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is often used in this case is
$$
|f(n)| \leq \operatorname{const} g(n)
$$
or
$$
|f| \leq \operatorname{const} g
$$
or
$$
|f| \leq C\, g.
$$
where it is understood that the constant does not depend on $n$.

However, it sometimes depends on the context, if $C$ can depend on $f$ and $g$.

I do not think that this is a standard notation.